# How to change value of longitude and latitude dyanimically without reloading whole web page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am working on tracking application in PHP , i want to change values of longitude and latitude of  vehicle  dynamically without reloading map , but these latlong values are coming from android tracking device  , so what should i do ? Does it possible through AJAX or Javascript or is there any option to do this.

Comment: Post the related code. And also the options that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing so much about the other components in your system, I would recommend that you save the coordinates from the Android device in a database. Then your map can check for updates in the database with Ajax, and update the position if needed.

The benefit of this is simplicity, you don't have to create a connection between the web page and the Android device. And you also have the possibility to track old positions, since they are always saved in the database.